# ECDSA Not Signing/Verifying Correctly

Tags: c++, cryptography, signing, crypto++, ecdsa

I am currently having trouble signing/verifying a string with Crypto++. I have tried methods listed on this website among others, for months, with no success. I have previously tried the C style solution posted here: http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_Digital_Signature_Algorithm, but am currently working on the implementation using filters.

My attempt below is a modification of the solution posted here: [Get ECDSA signature with Crypto++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21024399/get-ecdsa-signature-with-crypto).

The following code outputs the error:
`ERROR: VerifierFilter: digital signature not valid`

```
ECDSA<ECP, SHA256>::PrivateKey privateKey;
ECDSA<ECP, SHA256>::PublicKey publicKey;

AutoSeededRandomPool prng, rrng;

privateKey.Initialize(prng, CryptoPP::ASN1::secp256k1());

privateKey.MakePublicKey(publicKey);

string signature;

signature.erase();

string message = "Do or do not. There is no try.";

StringSource(message, true,
     new SignerFilter(rrng,
     ECDSA<ECP, SHA256>::Signer(privateKey),
     new StringSink(signature)));

 try
 {
     StringSource(signature + message, true,
         new SignatureVerificationFilter(
         ECDSA<ECP, SHA256>::Verifier(publicKey), NULL,
         SignatureVerificationFilter::THROW_EXCEPTION
         ) // SignatureVerificationFilter   
         ); // StringSource 
 }
 catch (CryptoPP::Exception& e)
 {
     std::cerr << "\n\nERROR: " << e.what() << std::endl;
 }
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After browsing the Wiki longer, I think I may have stumbled on the solution.

http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/SignatureVerificationFilter#Signature_Generation_and_Verification

> In the example above, the filter receives a concatenation of
>   message+signature. When SIGNATURE_AT_BEGIN is not specified in the
>   constructor, SIGNATURE_AT_END is implied and the signature to be
>   verified must be presented after the message. If the signature is
>   inserted first, SIGNATURE_AT_BEGIN must be be specified as an
>   additional flags value as shown below.

Because `THROW_EXCEPTION` is used, `signature` and `message` must be swapped, or `SIGNATURE_AT_BEGIN` must be added. In this case, the following code does not throw an exception.

```
StringSource ss(signature + message, true,
    new SignatureVerificationFilter(
    verifier, NULL,
    THROW_EXCEPTION | SIGNATURE_AT_BEGIN
        ) // SignatureVerificationFilter   
        ); // StringSource
```

Answer (score 0):

```
StringSource(signature + message, true,
    new SignatureVerificationFilter(
        ECDSA<ECP, SHA256>::Verifier(publicKey), NULL,
        SignatureVerificationFilter::THROW_EXCEPTION
    ) // SignatureVerificationFilter   
); //
```

The above looks fishy. It looks fishy for two reasons. First, it uses anonymous declarations, and I know some versions of GCC gives bad results with them. GCC generates code such that the destructors run too soon. So name your declaration.

Second, the `SignatureVerificationFilter` takes a reference, and not a temporary. So you should provide a reference to the `verifier`, or use the `Ref()` member function if its available.

First, try with just:

```
ECDSA<ECP, SHA256>::Verifier verifier(publicKey);

StringSource ss(signature + message, true,
    new SignatureVerificationFilter(
        verifier, NULL,
        SignatureVerificationFilter::THROW_EXCEPTION
    ) // SignatureVerificationFilter   
); // StringSource
```

Second, try with:

```
StringSource ss(signature + message, true,
    new SignatureVerificationFilter(
        ECDSA<ECP, SHA256>::Verifier(publicKey).Ref(), NULL,
        SignatureVerificationFilter::THROW_EXCEPTION
    ) // SignatureVerificationFilter   
); // StringSource
```

But I'm not sure if `ECDSA<ECP, SHA256>::Verifier(publicKey).Ref()` is going to work.

Comment: @stacker - I see where you got the the code (sadly, I'm the guy who probably wrote it). I will get those wiki pages fixed the next time I come up for air.

Comment: @ jww - Neither option worked out for me. I applied your modifications in the first solution to my signing as well, with no luck. Also, Ref() apparently isn't a member. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @stacker - apply the same changes in the signer code in case that's creating a bad signature (which would explain the failed verification).

Comment: Okay, well I had kept my code the same, only replacing the two above excerpts. Then I modified the signing part afterwards, all three attempts failed. Is the Verifier the only way to troubleshoot the signing process? Thanks.

Comment: I just posted an answer to my question. Can you confirm that this is correct? Thanks.